# I can not open my Main ( administrative ) account with my used password

Tags: login

My Ubuntu is not opening when I use my administration account. My Ubuntu is 12.04 version.

My other user account (which are not password protected) are opening. But I can not access my administrative account through the user account. I can not do anything (update, upgrade, accessing my files,..).

The main problem when ever I give my password it does not open my account like it was opening in past. When I am in my administrative account then I can not shutdown and restart my computer too. It get stocked; I have to forcefully shutdown.

So the problem is not with the password (as it is the correct password) the problem is something else which I can not figure out.

Please help me and guide how to regain my access to my administrative (main) account.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal on your "non-protected" user. Then type this:

```
sudo su
passwd (your user)
```

After that change your password (or type your old password). After that try to login with your new password. Hope that it solved your problem.

Comment: I followed your guidelines

Comment: then the following messages was shown

Comment: guest-iyhvrk@aum-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$ sudo su
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [125, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
guest-iyhvrk@aum-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~$

Comment: I have one administrator and one guest/user account.My Guest/user  account does not accept any sudo command. So what should I do. How can I access the administrative account.

Comment: I noticed when I use a wrong password then it shows that invalid password at the same time when I use the correct password it works but not open the main windows...again it come back to the starting page and ask to enter the correct password...it has been getting to my nerve.